# Paypal Recurring Payments using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm new with PayPal API and I'm implementing the recurring payments based on [Pedro Alonso's](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/paypal-integration-part-2-paypal-rest-api--cms-22917) tutorial. Nowadays my application is able to create/activate the Billing Plan and create/execute the Billing Agreement.

I'm not sure if I have to do something more or just have to wait the payments start to be executed and monitor them throgh the webhook events. [The Handling Recurring Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) says that I should call DoExpressCheckoutPayment and CreateRecurringPaymentProfile but I didn't find this API's corresponding calls on Paypal's .NET SDK (installed via nuget). The documentation does't say if the Agreement.Execute method do this or if I have to call another method to accomplish the subscribe process.

In the Sandbox environment I can see just the "Billing subscription created" event and the payment status created (when logged as the payer). I suppose that should exist a "Payment capture completed" event and the status should be Active or something like this.

In fact I think the SDK documentation is poor compared to the other.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is using the REST API.  DoExpressCheckoutPayment and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile are part of the Classic API (NVP, XML).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But I still don't know if the Execute method do the trick or if I have to call other method to.